# Deleting a movie with many to many relations

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have this SQL database setup:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/GtszOPL.png]

I have a movie now with 2 genres and 2 actors. I want to delete the movie and its not possible with just:

```
movie = (Movie)listBoxMovieExistingMovies.SelectedItem;
db.Movies.Remove(movie);
db.SaveChanges();
LoadMovieExistingMovies();
```

I understand that i have to remove the relationsships first but i cant figure out how to do that.

edit:

(How i create MovieActor and MovieGenres)

```
CREATE TABLE MovieGenre
(
MovieID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Movie(MovieID),
GenreID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Genre(GenreID),
PRIMARY KEY(MovieID,GenreID)
```

)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @webdad3, the diagram shows the foreign keys.

Comment: Is that code throwing an exception?

Comment: MovieGenres and MovieActors both contain two foreign keys which inside it self combines to one primary key

CREATE TABLE MovieGenre
(
MovieID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Movie(MovieID),
GenreID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Genre(GenreID),
PRIMARY KEY(MovieID,GenreID)
)

Comment: the error message is the following:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: See the inner exception for details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to select the movie from your context first?

```
movie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MovieId == ((Movie)listBoxMovieExistingMovies.SelectedItem).MovieId);
db.Movies.Remove(movie);
db.SaveChanges();
LoadMovieExistingMovies();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with cascade delete on the db

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MovieActor](
    [MovieId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActorId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MovieActor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MovieActor_Actor] FOREIGN KEY([ActorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Actor] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MovieActor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MovieActor_Actor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MovieActor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MovieActor_Movie] FOREIGN KEY([MovieId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Movie] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MovieActor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MovieActor_Movie]
GO
```

If you adopte this solution, please take time to read about cascade.

Comment: sorry but im quite new to programming, what you gave me makes no sense :/

Comment: before removing, you must ensure that the entity you are removing exists in the database and is known of the object (said DbContext) you use to do the removing. Two ways for that : querying the db as suggested by Troy, or attaching a local entity to the context as illustrated by the above code.

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__MovieActo__Movie__1920BF5C". The conflict occurred in database "MovieCollection", table "dbo.MovieActor", column 'MovieID'.
The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__MovieActo__Movie__1920BF5C". The conflict occurred in database "MovieCollection", table "dbo.MovieActor", column 'MovieID'.
The statement has been terminated."
Time: 2013-12-03 16:17:27

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do it

1:

```
movie = (Movie)listBoxMovieExistingMovies.SelectedItem;
            var queryMovie = db.Movies.Include("Genres").Include("Actors").First(m => m.MovieID==movie.MovieID);
db.Movies.Remove(queryMovie);
```

2:

```
    movie = (Movie)listBoxMovieExistingMovies.SelectedItem;
    movie.Actors.Clear();
    movie.Genres.Clear();
    db.Movies.Remove(movie);
    db.SaveChanges();
```